# Accessing Arrays in dataLayer and sending to a Custom Dimension

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I do have an event called **Purchase**, in which features product & subCategory parameters. Here's how the event is set in dataLayer. Please keep in mind that the value of product & subCategory parameters are always changing. Also sometimes the index will have 5 items, sometimes only 1.

```
  dataLayer.push({
  event: 'Purchase',
  products: [
    {product: 'abc-111-aaaaa-1198', subCategory: 'Dresses'},
    {product: 'def-222-aaaaa-0002', subCategory: 'Skirts'},
    {product: 'ghz-333-aaaaa-0002', subCategory: 'Jackets'}
  ],
  gtm.uniqueEventId: 9999
})
```

I would like to be able to concatenate product & subCategory parameters into single custom dimension as a single value. The way to do is probably creating a Custom Javascript variable, since I don't have proficiency in JS, I am unable to produce the below output.

Final output should be:

```
"'abc-111-aaaaa-1198|Dresses','def-222-aaaaa-0002|Skirts', 'ghz-333-aaaaa-0002|Jackets'"
```

Would be great to have your JS code to produce the desired output!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap

I have also included an example.

```
const products = [
    {product: 'abc-111-aaaaa-1198', subCategory: 'Dresses'},
    {product: 'def-222-aaaaa-0002', subCategory: 'Skirts'},
    {product: 'ghz-333-aaaaa-0002', subCategory: 'Jackets'}
  ]
  
  const result = products.flatMap(x => x.product + "|" + x.subCategory);
  
  console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hey Rafel, Indeed your code gives the correct results. However values of product & subCategory are always changing. Is there a solution which is not hard coded?

Comment: the key is always changing? that is a different question.

Comment: yes indeed, I've added the detail to the issue. sorry for ambiguity.

Comment: as long as the key, product and subCategory are the same the code should work for any length of array. 

const result = products.flatMap(x => x.product + "|" + x.subCategory)

Comment: I went through the GTM documentation and seems like ES6 is not supported - so do arrows functions. So we should be getting what we want by defining a function and returning a value, it seems like.